# In Java, can a static method return an array of objects as its result?

Tags: java, arrays, object, static-methods, return-type

In java, can a static method return an array of objects as its result? I'm pretty sure that you can return an array of objects just fine in some cases, but I also know that most objects use instance variables which are non-static. Help with my confusion please.

Comment: What happened when you tried to create and call a `static` method that returns an array of objects?

Comment: Please be more clear

Comment: a static method can return the same as not static methods. you can quickly test yourself, instead of creating a account and posting a question here...

Comment: The answer is yes, a static method can return an array of objects. You seem to be confused about the difference between static and non-static. The ONLY difference is that non-static variables & methods work with an instance of the class, whereas static methods/variables no not have a reference to an object

Comment: @rgettman: Don't be rude, it simple might happen, that he miss some special case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Instance variables in other objects are not a limitation for you. Limitation for static method is it cannot access instance variables without the instance, but while you have an instances to return everything is fine.

Answer to that question can be tricky, see this:

http://ideone.com/B7uHMt

```
import java.util.*;

class StaticTest {

    Object[] arr = new Object[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    static Object[] testMethod() {
        //return arr; // you do not have an instance
        //return new String[] { "abc", "def" }; // possible
        StaticTest o = new StaticTest();
        return o.arr;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        System.out.println( Arrays.asList( testMethod() ) );
    }

}
```

If you uncomment `return arr;`, there is an error

> error: non-static variable arr cannot be referenced from a static context

but problem is different, not the case, that array cannot be returned.

Answer (score 4):

Of course a static method can return an array of objects. Being static doesn't limit the allowed return types.

The static method would have to construct the array of objects that it returns (unless it takes it from some static field initialized elsewhere).